# Blogger changing alt tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

Hiya guys i'm having trouble changing the alt tags dynamicly on blogger.

I tried the following script which works on my older blog as a test example, but i'm adding this to a blogger that uses the newest widgets.

```
<script>
$("img").each(function() {
$(this).attr('alt', '<data:title/>');
});
</script>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any errors/warnings on page? I hope you have jQuery script before that.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @WooCaSh i assume you mean the library, Yes it's in there

Comment: @PedroEstrada yes there is an error, it says can't TEMPLATE ERROR: No dictionary named, well I googled it, it means it does not work outside of the widget, so i placed the script inside the widget but seems in blogger your not allowed to place scripts in there. Can somebody point me into the right direction how i can right my own scripts which will work with blogger? Many thanks

Comment: well, what alt tag are you trying to add to all of the images?

Comment: sorry for the late response @AneeshJoseph it's the post.title that I want to add to the tag

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<data:post.title/>` instead

```
<script>
$("img").each(function() {
$(this).attr('alt', '<data:post.title/>');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("img").each(function() {
$(this).attr('alt', '<data:post.title/>');
});
</script>
```

The title of the blog is embedded in the JQuery code

```
data:blog.title
<data:post.title/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code automatically inserts the title into the image

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function(){
      var $img = $(this);
      var filename = $img.attr('src')
      $img.attr('alt', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
    });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function(){
      var $img = $(this);
      var filename = $img.attr('src')
      $img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
    });
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

see more https://www.cuongbv.com/2018/12/code-inserts-alt-tag-automatically-in-blogger.html